# How to render an element from a controller in cakephp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am having trouble figuring this out. I have an element named quoteform in my default layout. This element has a form which has a few textboxes, checkboxes, submit button etc. I would like to submit the form and send a mail with all this data. On successfully sending the mail, I would like to replace the current div with another div which says Message sent successfully.

I have used cakephp ajax to do this but on submit, it doesnt send a mail or refresh the div with the message.

Following is my code

*Quotes/quoteform.ctp*

```
<?php
$this->requestAction('Quotes/index');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="quotenext">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Quote'); ?>
    <div class="inputboxa"><?php echo $this->Form->input(
            'name', array(
            'id' => 'name',
            'style' => 'width:440px;height:20px;font-size:8pt; background-color:black;color:white;resize:none;border:none;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;',
            'placeholder' => 'NAME*', 'type' => 'textarea'
        )); ?></div>
    <br>

    <div class="inputboxb"><?php echo $this->Form->input(
            'email', array(
            'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'E-MAIL*',
            'style' => 'width:440px;font-size:8pt;height:20px;resize:none;background-color:black;color:white;border:none;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;',
            'type' => 'textarea'
        )); ?></div>
    <br>

    <div class="inputboxc"><?php echo $this->Form->input(
            'phone', array(
            'id' => 'phone', 'placeholder' => 'PHONE*',
            'style' => 'width:440px;font-size:8pt;height:20px;resize:none;background-color:black;color:white;border:none;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;',
            'type' => 'textarea'
        )); ?></div>
    <br>

    <?php

    echo $this->Js->submit(
        'SUBMIT', array(
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#quotenext')->effect('hide'),
        'update' => $this->Js->get('#quotesent')->effect('show')
    )); ?>
    <!--</a>-->
    div id="quotesent" class="slide" style="display:none"">


    <div id="quotebottom">
        <div id="message">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <div id="closediv">CLOSE</div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*QuotesController.php*

```
class QuotesController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('jquery1.9.1.min'));
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {

        $email = new CakeEmail();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Quote->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->Quote->save($this->request->data)) {
                if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {

                    $name = $this->request->data['Quote']['name'];
                    $mail = $this->request->data['Quote']['email'];
                    $email->from(array($mail => $name));
                    $email->to('anniecherian79@gmail.com');
                    if (isset($this->request->data['Quote']['solutioncheckbox'])) {
                        $ctime = implode(',', $this->request->data['Quote']['solutioncheckbox']);
                    }
                    $message = "Phone No : " . $this->request->data['Quote']['phone'] . "\n\nBest Contact time :" . $ctime . " \n\nMessage : " . $this->request->data['Quote']['message'];
                    $email->subject('BlackNova Website Instant Quote Form');
                    $email->send($message);

                    if ($email->send($message)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Quote Processed..Thank You For Visiting Our Website!!!');
                        $this->render('/view/elements/quotes/quoteform.ctp');

                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

In short, on successfully ending the mail, I would like to display the message in #quotesent, is this possible?

Comment: Shouldn't 'div id="quotesent" class="slide" style="display:none"">' be '<div id="quotesent" class="slide" style="display:none">'? Or is it mistyped?

Comment: @Leah, you need to work out where the problem is; it's either in your JavaScript, or in the CakePHP controller. Using Firebug or Developer Tools (in Chrome) check that the response from the server is what you're expecting. If it is, then you know the culprit is CakePHP, if not, JavaScript is being naughty!

Comment: @foxns7-<div id="quotesent" class="slide" style="display:none">, it was just a typo i guess...

Comment: @sam Delaney-I am not sure but do you think I have rendered the element right from the controller?

Comment: You don´t say if you check that the call to the controller is made, use requestAction this way 
$this->requestAction(  array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'featured');
is the recommended way by CakePHP